# Customize meta box through child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, customization, meta-boxes

I am using penny auction wordpress theme, as i am new to wordpress. My question is to add more fields in side meta-box by using child theme, So for this I have successfully created and activated child theme, but I am stuck here to how can I add more text fields in meta box by using child theme functions file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is to install the Meta Box plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/meta-box/), then add this to your child theme's functions.php file:

```
function yourprefix_register_meta_boxes( $meta_boxes ) {
    $prefix = 'metaboxprefix_';

    $meta_boxes[] = array(
        'id'         => 'samplefield',
        'title'      => __( 'Your Meta Box Title', 'yourtextdomain' ),
        'post_types' => 'post',
        'context'    => 'normal',
        'priority'   => 'high',
        'fields' => array(
            array(
                'name'  => __( 'Your Text Field', 'yourtextdomain' ),
                'id'    => $prefix . 'yourfieldid',
                'type'  => 'text',
            ),
        )
    );

    return $meta_boxes;
}
add_filter( 'rwmb_meta_boxes', 'yourprefix_register_meta_boxes' );
```

For future reference: http://metabox.io/